# Nested arrays in a POST request are not parsed completely by PHP

Tags: php, post

I have been researching this problem for over 12 hours now, with no success.

We have a large custom CMS we have built for a governmental client.  The software was developed on PHP 5.3.3.  The initial deployment was done on PHP 5.2.2, which caused a few problems, but they finally upgraded their server to PHP 5.3.8. We have little control on exactly which versions gets deployed to their servers.

We have encountered a show-stopper problem.  We have an AJAX request which submits a large form via POST with up to 5 levels deep of nested arrays.  This has worked fine for several months, but all of a sudden using the new PHP install, we are only getting a partial decode of the data inside the $_POST variable.  I have confirmed that PHP is received all the data by inspecting php://input (I also checked that the data was being sent from the browser via Firebug).

This is what we are receiving as the decoded output (via var_dump, I've shortened it for brevity, this should give you a good idea)

```
Array
(
    [db_required_fields] => Array
        (
            [awr_title] => Array
                (
                    [en] => phil test eng
                )

        )

    [subtitle_intro] => Array
        (
            [awr_subtitle] => Array
                (
                    [en] =>
                )

        )
[products] => Array
    (
        [cp_recall] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [product_common_name] => Array
                            (
                                [en] =>
                            )

                    )

            )

        )
)
```

What is missing:  each of the [en] should have a peer [fr] array index entry. For example, there should be a [fr] phil test fr entry. Several other index entries at the 2nd array level are missing.  The request data itself is not particularly large, roughly 6-7Kb.

What I've done:
- I have had suhosin disabled since it was often mentioned as the cause of similar problems.
- Pored over the phpinfo(); from both a working and the now-working server, trying to identify relevant differences.
-  Investigated every module and option within which might affect things (mbstring, for example).

I am now considering writing my own parser for the php://input data, but this seems fraught with (potentially hidden) danger.

Any suggestion or hint ?

Comment: How exactly are you transmitting this data to the server? Via a form? If so, what are that form's attributes? Or are you using a cURL POST request from another PHP script? Or even an AJAX POST from the client side?

Comment: As mentioned in my question, it is an AJAX POST.

Comment: Can you share the array you are posting from your form? your JS and PHP also please.

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest serializing the post data before sending it. And I would send it as a single string of JSON in one "field." Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'YOUR URL',
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify(form_data) // Where form_data is the JSON object.
    },
    success: function(response)
    {
        // Do stuff.
    }
});
```

Then on the server-side, json_decode as follows:

```
<?php

$_POST = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);

?>
```

**EDIT:**

You want json_decode instead of unserialize. Whoops.

Comment: I like this suggestion, we will be trying this. Thank you.

Comment: As it turns out, putting the data into json would probably work, but I have found out this problem would then manifest itself in several other places.  We will have  to try to fix the PHP install instead of working around on the problem in this case.  Still a good suggestion, however. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably being affected by the new PHP configuration variables [max_input_nesting_level](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-nesting-level) or [max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) (particularly the latter). Try setting it to a higher value so that PHP doesn't start ignoring some input.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that when you want to change settings like *max_input_vars* and *max_input_nesting_level* and you have **Suhosin** running, you also need to change these params for Suhosin. Example for *max_input_vars*:

You need to add this to the .htaccess file:

```
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 4000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 4000
```

You also need to add the following to your php.ini file in order to allow the change of the suhosin parameters within the .htaccess:

```
suhosin.perdir = "pr"
```

"p" allows the change for "post" settings, "r" for request settings.